# Return the polygon that lat long resides within using SQL Spatial Data types (STIntersect/STContains etc)

Tags: sql, sql-server, geospatial, spatial

I have researched this for two days now and cannot find anything that works for me, it may be my database design, but I *think* it's designed ok.

I have a table called "post_codes_new", it contains the following columns;

```
id (int)
post_code (varchar, example: "0612")
post_code_name (varchar, example: "Henderson")
latlongs (geography data type - forming a polygon)
```

What I am attempting to do is query this table using a lat/long point to return any post_codes record that contains that lat/long (any record that the lat/long falls within the boundaries of).

Here's what I've been working on;

```
DECLARE @point geography;
SET @point = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(174.94280000 -36.75000000)',4326)
select post_code
from dbo.post_codes_new
WHERE latlongs.MakeValid().STContains(@point) = 1;
```

No matter what lat/long point I enter here, my query returns me 931 of the 1081 records in that table and it takes 22 seconds.... It should only return one record. And I'm hoping for way better performance of course.

I'm trying to achieve this;

```
['PSEUDO-CODE' QUERY OF WHAT I'D LIKE TO ACHIEVE]
SELECT post_codes.* FROM post_codes WHERE latlongs.STIntersects(myLatLongPoint) = 1
```

The examples I have looked at (on this site and elsewhere) all seem to work with polygons that are defined within the query (ie, the points are listed in the query body explicitly). I have seen a few that look at records containing polygon boundaries, but none have worked for me.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd like to have a play with this - have you got sample data I can use to experiment?

Comment: A couple of things that usually trip people up. The orientation of polygons (i.e. clockwise or counter-clockwise) matters. Using the same boundaries, defining the polygon one way will define the area that you're expecting; defining it the other way will specify the entire Earth with a hole defined by your polygon. So, if your polygons are defined as such, that could explain why you're getting more intersections than you expect. The other is: are you using a spatial index? For 1000 rows, that should be relatively quick (assuming decent hardware, etc).

Comment: Sorry for my very late reply Tomc and Ben Thul. Thank you for replying. I'll try the reversal as I have found some info that talked about clockwise/anti-clockwise etc. If that doesn't solve the issues I'm having I'll place some example code up for you to look at. Bear in mind that one of these polygons has over 44,000 points (it's a complicated coastal post code area in New Zealand). Cheers.

Comment: By the way, just as an aside, if I take one of my postcodes from the database and add it into the STGeomFromText() function inline with a query, it works as expected. It's only if I just query it directly from the database field that it stops working (which indicates that the issue may lay within the field data). I got no errors importing that data and did not reverse it when I put it in, so I am assuming it's OK... I may be wrong.

Comment: I saw this (about STUnion) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66671/change-polygon-handedness-for-sql-2008-reverse-polygon-vertex-order but I have never had that hemisphere error appear. I tried STUnion like so ->[code] 
    DECLARE @g geography;
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(174.60000000 -39.00000000)',4326)
select *
from dbo.post_codes_new
WHERE latlong.MakeValid().STUnion(latlong.MakeValid()).STIntersects(@g) = 1;[/code]
But no difference, still 931 records of my 1081 being returned.

Answer (score 0):

Huge thanks to @BenThul and @TomC. It turned out that indeed, my points had been entered in a clockwise direction, which wraps the "rest of the world excluding your polygon" and creates that as a polygon area - hence the 931 out of 1081 records being returned in my query.

So I took my existing polygon points (that I had stored as a nvarchar(MAX) string, alongside my geography column) and reversed them, then over-wrote my geography column with those reversed values. I then ran the queries on a few known address/postcode combinations and it worked perfectly. A single postcode was returned per query, as expected. Brilliant!

It takes (consistently) 16 seconds for the query to run, but I'll work on that speed problem as a separate issue.

Thank you guys.